# What is the correct notation for a sub-sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to say that a sequence is a subsequence of $A_n$ for all even indexes,
is it valid to write it as 
$$ k\in \mathbb{N},\, n > k$$
$$(B_k){\,^\infty_{k=1}} = (A_n){\,^\infty_{n=2k}} $$
or 
 $$  (A_{2k}){\, ^\infty_{k=1}}$$ ?

if not, what is the correct manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right notation is $(A_{2n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to write just as $A_{2n}$. It is also Okay!